# How To Call XML Service With AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, xml

I know that AngularJS prefers JSON, but I can't get my Web API to work with JSON.  I've tried for 3 days and I'm not going to try anymore.  I can get it to return XML.  Can I retrieve the XML data with AngularJS?  I have written the $http call below and it always fails with no status text.  I've tried asking for XML type and I've tried the default call.  You can see that all 3 of these URLs return XML data in the browser:

```js
http://stevegaines.info/api/Exams?id=3&extra=0
http://stevegaines.info/api/Exams/4
http://stevegaines.info/api/values


$http.get(url)
    .then(function (dataResponse)
    {
        $scope.Exams = dataResponse.data;
    }, function (error)
    {
        alert("error.statusText = " + error.statusText);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just tried to call your api with $http service and it works ok. I think you should start investigating this problem with looking at network tab in chrome developer tools when making such a request.

Comment: Thanks for giving it a try.  I'm surprised that it worked for you.  I'm going to try checking the network tab again, but every time I dug into the response it just said "An error has occurred".  Maybe I'll try creating a new project that has nothing but that one line of code to be sure something else in my code is not causing the problem.

Comment: I tried calling this URL again and discovered, that you need add `www.` to your address, because e.g. get request on `http://stevegaines.info/api/Exams?id=3&extra=0` returns 301 response moved permanently, so no data can be parsed. I think it helps.

Comment: Brilliant.  Adding "www." worked.  Such a little change.  That's one of those things where I go "Doh!".  Or "Why didn't I think of that?"  Thanks a lot.